# IoC container implementation in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I want to use the IoC container in a method to check a logged in users company code when they submit a payment. I have two certificates in my settings class and an IF else statement to differentiate between each one.

```
      public static string FDGCreditCardUserID
    {
        get
        {
            if (BillingController.currentcompanycode == 5)
                return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["5FDGCreditCardUserID"];
            else
                return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["6FDGCreditCardUserID"];
        }
    }
    public static string FDGCreditCardPassword
    {
        get
        {
            if (BillingController.currentcompanycode == 5)
                return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["5FDGCreditCardPassword"];
            else
                return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["6FDGCreditCardPassword"];
        }
    }
```

Then in my IoC container

```
  x.For<IFDGService>().Use<FDGService>().SetProperty(s =>
            {
                s.Url = Settings.FDGURL;
                s.UserID = Settings.FDGCreditCardUserID;
                s.Password = Settings.FDGCreditCardPassword;
                s.Certificate = Settings.FDGCreditCardCertFilePath;  
            });
```

I have an FDGService that checks credentials but does not return to the IoC on payment submit to check the company code and apply the correct certificate.

SubmitPayment Method where the creditcard control contains the correct company code when i run it.

How do i get my application to select the correct certificate based on the updated company code. Seeing as users can have different company codes based on policies selected for payment. One company code at the moment can either be 5 or 6.

```
  public ActionResult SubmitPayment([ConvertJSON]List<PayModel> payments)
    {  
        List<TransactionModel> transactions = new List<TransactionModel>();
        foreach (var pymt in payments)
        {
            var policyNumber = pymt.PolicyNumber.Trim();
            TransactionModel trans = new TransactionModel() { Payment = pymt };

            if (pymt.Selected)
            {
                var creditCardControl = UpdateCreditCardControl(policyNumber);
```

Comment: What does the constructor for the controller look like where the `IFDGService` is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using StructureMap it uses "Greedy Initialization", meaning when the constructor is called it will call the constructor with the most amount of arguments or parameters passed in.

```
private IFDGService service;

public MyController(IFDGService service)
{
    this.service = service;
}
```

Then `service` will be available after `IoC.Configure()` is called.

Call `IoC.Configure()` whereever the application is started. google "where does Mvc start" or something like that.

to change the company code set it somewhere other than an instance variable in the controller, like a `static` class, I know static is bad, get it working and then make it better, since that would be complex to modify, and then `get; set;` when you need to.

I have to go to meeting, kinda rushed, hope that helps